# Give string arguments in a fortran program

Tags: string, file, input, arguments, fortran

I have this `fortran` code

```
    REAL E(5000),R(5000),B,C,D,F,H
       INTEGER Y(5000)
       OPEN(UNIT=15,FILE='INPUT.dat',STATUS='OLD')
       DO 40, I=1,4095
       READ(15,*) E(I),Y(I)
       R(I)=Y(I)*1.
 40    ENDDO
       CLOSE(15)
       OPEN(UNIT=25,FILE='OUTPUT.dat',STATUS='UNKNOWN')
       DO 60 I=1,300
       WRITE(25,*) E(I),R(I)
 60    ENDDO
       DO 50 K=300,1325
       J=K
       B=1.07
       C=0.93
       D=R(K+1)/R(K)
          IF(D.GE.B.OR.D.LE.C)THEN
C           F=(R(K-6)+R(K-5)+R(K-4))/3.
C           H=(R(K+6)+R(K+5)+R(K+4))/3.
C           R(J+1)=(F+H)/2
          R(J+1)=(R(K-2)+R(K-1)+R(K))/3.
          ENDIF
       WRITE(25,*) E(J+1),R(J+1)
 50    ENDDO
       DO 70 I=1327,4095
       WRITE(25,*) E(I),R(I)
 70    ENDDO
       CLOSE(25)
       STOP
       END
```

This program takes as an input the file `INPUT.dat`, processes it and writes the file `OUTPUT.dat`. Also inside 60, 50 and 70 loops there are some numbers : 300 and 1325. What I would like to do is compile the code once and then execute it using

```
code(INPUT, OUTPUT, 300, 1325)
```

but I don't know how(or if this is supported) to do this in fortran. Is it possible to be done?

**EDIT**

As suggested by @High Performance Mark, @M.S.B.  I took a look at `get_command_argument()` but I don't know how to use it. For instance, a wiki example to use it is the following

```
program test_get_command_argument
  integer :: i
  character(len=32) :: arg

  i = 0
  do
    call get_command_argument(i, arg)
    if (len_trim(arg) == 0) exit

    write (*,*) trim(arg)
    i = i+1
  end do
end program
```

I want to have program that will accept arguments : strings and integers that is. For instance, in the above example I would like to do

`test_get_command_argument("INPUT", "OUTPUT", 300, 1325)`

Is something like that possible?

Comment: If your compiler is up to date you can use the intrinsic subroutine `get_command_argument` to read arguments from the command line. Judging by your posting this might bring a rush of exhilaration to your coding practices as you fast forward into the 21st century so take a deep breath and hang on tight.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark : Thank you very much for your comment! The thing is that this is not my code! I have to use it for "political" reasons, but I don't know fortran. As far as the compiler is concerned I am using the default compiler that ubuntu 12.04 offers.

Comment: Probably you are using gfortran.  Try the compile command and `-v` to find out.  See http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/command_argument_count and http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/get_command_argument for info on accessing arguments on the command line, as suggested in the first comment.   Use the variable "read" with `get_command_argument` with the `file` keyword of the `open` statement instead of the current specific file name.

Comment: You should learn at least some basic Fortran before trying to adapt any code to your needs.

Comment: What kind of shell do you use? Or from where do you want to call it?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.04. I don't want to call it from somewhere. Just like a C++ or Java program I want to define the fortran program like `program(String "in", String "out", int x, int y) {main code}` and run it like `program(INPUT, OUTPUT, 300, 1325)`.

Comment: Read something about passing command line parameters in general. The syntax you want is not possible. Then read some manual about `get_command_argument`. And read something about Fortran if you want to do stuff in it.

Comment: To "read" two command-line arguments, you have to call `get_command_argument` twice.  Please read the explanation on the Fortranwiki.